# Vue.js - Dynamic component and events

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm wondering how to deal with `dynamic components` and `events` using `vue-js 2.3`.

Let's say the component `home` `$emit('eventFromHome')` and the component `archives` `$emit('eventFromArchives')`

What is the way to catch them in the `<component></component>` ? Does it exist a better/nicer way to do it than the temporary solution?

#### Dynamic component

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    currentView: 'home'
  },
  components: {
    home: { /* ... */ },
    posts: { /* ... */ },
    archive: { /* ... */ }
  }
})

<component v-bind:is="currentView"></component>
```

#### Static component

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    currentView: 'home'
  },
  components: {
    home: { /* ... */ },
    posts: { /* ... */ },
    archive: { /* ... */ }
  }
})

<home v-on:eventFromHome=""></home>
<archive v-on:eventFromArchive=""></archive>
```

#### Temporary answer

```
<component 
    v-bind:is="currentView"
    v-on:eventFromHome=""
    v-on:eventFromArchive="">
</component>
```

Comment: You can just add both `@eventFromHome` and `@eventFromArchives` to the dynamic component.

Comment: So it would be something like `<component v-on:eventFromHome="" v-on:eventFromArchive="" v-bind:is="currentView"></component>` ? That is what you are saying ?

Comment: Yep, that's correct. There might be a more elegant solution, but nothing's coming to mind.

Comment: Well, in the case we have let's say 30 events it will look bad for sure :/ ...

Comment: True, but I'd argue that that's a code smell that one component is trying to handle too many events.

Comment: If you have 30 events you might want to use a centralized event bus. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add both `@eventFromHome` and `@eventFromArchives` to the dynamic component:

```
<component 
  :is="currentView"
  @eventFromHome="eventHandlerFoo" 
  @eventFromArchive="eventHandlerBar"
></component>
```

Answer (score 5):

Since Vue.js 2.4, [`v-on` has an object syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on) that allows dynamic event bindings.

With that, the solution is much more elegant:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    currentView: {
      component: 'home',
      events: {}, // <-- put listeners here
    }
  },
  components: {
    home: { /* ... */ },
    posts: { /* ... */ },
    archive: { /* ... */ }
  }
})

<component v-bind:is="currentView.component" v-on="currentView.events"></component>
```

Comment: In this case, each event inside `events`, would be `'event-emitted-name' : this.parentUpdateFunction`

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the best practice is some thing like following approach. the idea is building a directive that attaches some listeners and handlers to dynamic components. thanks [Javier Lecuona](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/dynamic-props-and-custom-event-emit-in-dynamic-component/10932) for his idea:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <component :is="component" v-bind="dynamicProps" v-dynamic-events="knownEvents"></component>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import CoolComponent from './cool-component.vue';

export default {
  directives: {
    DynamicEvents: {
      bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
        const allEvents = binding.value;
        allEvents.forEach((event) => {
          // register handler in the dynamic component
          vnode.componentInstance.$on(event, (eventData) => {
            // when the event is fired, the proxyEvent function is going to be called
            vnode.context.proxyEvent(event, eventData);
          });
        });
      },
      unbind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
        vnode.componentInstance.$off();
      },
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      component: CoolComponent,
      dynamicProps: {
        isThisCool: true,
      },
      knownEvents: ['event-1', 'event-2']
    };
  },
  methods: {
    proxyEvent(eventName, eventData) {
      // called by the custom directive
      // do whatever you please with the event :)
    }
  }
};

</script>
```